# Storing large number of UIImage's in file for animation

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to store huge number of UIImage's into a file and read it. The options I'm thinking of are:

1. Turn images into NSData and save each to corresponding file ("1.png", "2.png", etc.) and later read them.
2. Turn images into NSData and save to one large file, and also store the position of beginning of each image in the file. Then later open the file once and read them by using NSFileHandle's seekToFileOffset.

The reason I'm considering option 2 is because I am trying to implement an animation using these images. I wasn't sure if opening images one at a time would be fast enough for a high frame rate animation. Also there may be a better way I am not aware of yet. I would appreciate any kind of advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Other option could be

> 1. You can cache the image and  simultaneously store its file Path on a plist file and access it when ever necessary.

Its just another suggestion think over it!

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 has a method on UIImage that supports a sequence of images.

```
+ (UIImage *)animatedImageNamed:(NSString *)name duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

The documentation for the method's use is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

No need to optimise it prematurely.

The simplest and probably best solution is to have a naming convention for the images as you mentioned above. I'd actually add zeros to the left of the frame number so you are ok dealing with a higher frame count as well.

i.e. IMG_0001.png, IMG_0002.png etc

Create a UIImageView with the first image and create an frameIndex variable which you will use to keep track of the current animation frame and load the correct image.

Then schedule a NSTimer to run at your desired rate (i.e. 1/15 == 15FPS, 1/30 == 30FPS etc) and replace the current image on the UIImageView with a new one every time your NSTimer calls the selector.

Here's a quick example:

```
- (void)startAnimation
{
    self.currentFrame = 0;
    self.animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/30.f
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(_switchImage:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
}
```

And then on the `_switchImage` method:

```
- (void)_switchImage:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG_%04i", self.currentFrame];
    NSString *fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"png"];
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
        if (image) {
            self.animationImageView.image = image;
            self.currentFrame = self.currentFrame + 1;
            // If for any reason we reach the last animation frame, loop back to the beginning of the animation
            if (self.currentFrame > kLastAnimationFrame)
                self.currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Sounds like you will need to investigate a number of solutions...I think it can all depend on the number of image, their sizes, the frame rate you want them to appear etc etc

Start with the simplest solution and work through them until you find a fit.

To chip in yet another solution *(not the simplest)*. A variant of the all-in-one-file. You could use `[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:]` which bypasses the reading of a file (passing the content through buffers) and gives a straight memory access to the bytes.

*Please note that this method has been deprecated in iOS5 and `dataWithContentsOfFile:` is recommended as alternative, also the option `NSDataReadingMappedAlways` for it's bigger-brother seems to be what to use*

Memory mapped files can give fun features. Once I wrote a file sort using `qsort()` and `mmap()`
http://www.memention.com/blog/2011/05/04/That-old-thing.html

Answer (score 0):

You made no mention of the reason you are looking to do animation. So taking a shot in the dark, have you considered using Cocos 2D for your animation? There is a great tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32045/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-2-x

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be:
1. Create database file and load all the images into it.
2. At install time copy database file from assets folder to documents folder (if using phonegap/jquery, if not i assume there would some other way to do it).
3. Now you can use images as and when required, since (only a guess) database access is faster than file access.

Comment: The answer does not correspond to ios platform.. Please check the tags before you answer!